# MySQL importing CSV file with phpmyadmin without cell quotes

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a huge CSV file with the data like this:

```
ID~Name~Location~Price~Rating 
02~Foxtrot~Scotland~~9
08~Alpha~Iceland~9.90~4
32~ForestLane~Germany~14.35~
```

The issue is that when importing using PHPMyAdmin, it asks for `Columns enclosed with:` and `Columns escaped with:`. The trouble is, that this CSV doesn't have quotes for the cells.

If I leave this blank, it gives the error: `Invalid parameter for CSV import: Columns escaped with`

Is there a way to import without having quotes on the CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior. I'll bring it up on the phpMyAdmin development discussion list, but in the meantime, you can can work around it by using some nonsense character for "Columns escaped with" and leaving "Columns enclosed with" blank. Make sure your data doesn't contain, say a `"` or `£` and use that for "Columns escaped with". For instance, I have a data set where I know `£` doesn't exist, so I can use that for the "Columns escaped with" character -- if you don't have any escaped characters, you can enter any character there.

I'll update if I can provide any more useful information, but certainly that workaround should allow you to import your data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually ended up writing a script to do this in the end. Worked fine importing 500,000 lines without issue!

Comment: Just realized you are a contributer to phpmyadmin. I used this: `while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"~","'"))` The ' character actually worked fine in the end.

Comment: I've opened a feature request for this feature: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1552/ but I'm glad you were able to work it out on your own!